# MS Chart Control un-explode a pie point

Tags: asp.net, charts

I'm trying to un-explode, or implode, an exploded point in a pie chart.
However, when I explode a point it 'knows' it is exploded, but it doesn't appear that way on the chart.

```
Protected Sub Chart2_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageMapEventArgs) Handles Chart2.Click


    Dim pointIndex As Int32 = Int32.Parse(e.PostBackValue)

    If pointIndex >= 0 & pointIndex < Series1.Points.Count Then
        If Series1.Points(pointIndex)("Exploded") = "True" Then
            Series1.Points(pointIndex)("Exploded") = "False"
            Series1.Points(pointIndex).MapAreaAttributes += "onclick=""alert('Test explode alert');"""
        Else
            Series1.Points(pointIndex)("Exploded") = "True"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I do get the 'Test explode alert', but the pie point isn't visually exploded at that moment.
Removing the `Series1.Points(pointIndex)("Exploded") = "False"` makes the points visually exploded, but does not implode/un-explode them.

How can I implode or un-explode an exploded pie point?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help you but try to databind the chart before turning the points "exploded" to false. like in the example below:

```
Chart1.Databind();
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[0]["Exploded"] = "false";
```